# How to use Mac OS X's Summary Service on the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Can the 'summary service' be used on the command line in Mac OS X?

I have already tried piping, using the text file as an argument and sending the text file as stdin.

Comment: What were the commands you used to pipe the test file into the summary service?

Comment: cat textfile | $(locate SummaryService | grep MacOS | tail -1)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this AppleScript (say it's called summarize.scpt) and call from the command line using "osascript summarize.scpt `<n>`" where n is the number of desired summary sentences. This works on OS X 10.6.7. Just pipe the content in.

```
on run argv
  set stdin to do shell script "cat"
  set stdout to summarize stdin in (item 1 of argv)
end run
```

Alternately, you could use a one liner something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'set stdin to do shell script "cat"' -e "set stdout to summarize stdin in $1"
```

Comment: second one didn't work, first one tool a little tweaking - but overall it is great to know the applescript dictionary includes the summarize command.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without writing an application (AppleScript ObjC, or even a true Obj-C app) to interact with NSService, no. Even then Summary Service is exclusively a GUI application so it would bring up the GUI.

However some Services (if an Automator Workflow) can be run manually on the command line by using `automator` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There's also an open text summarization library called [libots](http://libots.sourceforge.net/) that includes a command line "ots" executable that one can pipe to.  Summary Service and OTS seem to give different results, in brief testing I'm not sure which one I would give higher marks.